# In Yolov7, how can I adjust the weight of certain training data for better model retraining?

Tags: object, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, training-data

I trained a yolov7 model on a public annotated data set. The model performs reasonable well on the public dataset. Next I tested this model against an annotated dataset, that I produced, the model is not performing well.

My plan is to take this annotated dataset and train the model, but this time the sample in this training set should weigh more in the cost function than the public dataset.

Normally for any other type of model, I would change a parameter of weight for each sample and fit the model. But I don't know how to do this for yolo model?